# IIS / PHP not passing (or passing incorrect) NTLM user information

Tags: php, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am currently migrating PHP applications from IIS 8.0 to IIS 10.0. NTLM/Windows Authentication has been installed through Server Manager, the scripts are running on PHP7.1, are using exactly the same configuration and files which were present in the old server, the configuration inside IIS is pretty much the same, the website on which I am trying to use it, has been converted into an application, Authentication is set to only Windows Authentication, is enabled, has both NTLM and Negotiate enabled, no extender protection enabled.

While running a script which has phpinfo in it, the user account shown under _SERVER["LOGON_USER"] is incorrect (shows the user, which I am using to connect to the server itself, not the user, who is connecting to the application from their own PC), not the current logged-on user. When trying to connect to the application, it requests me to log in, while it should take the user information automatically.

The only difference the old and new server is having, apart from version differences, is that the server runs only on HTTPS instead of mixed, yet even when turning off the redirect rule, it still requests to log in.

Expected behaviour would be that the application loads automatically and gets the information from the user's browser / 401 Challenge request without extra information required to be entered by the end user.

CGI has Impersonate User set to True.

Does anyone have an idea, which might be causing it, what should I check or what I could have missed?

[image: Screenshot from the server with the details changed to generic ones.]

Comment: Have you tried to disable CGI_IMPERSONation ?Besides, what REMOTE_USER did you see in phpinfo? LOGON_USER is the user account that client is impersonating to connect your web server. Now it is displaying the Logon user of your IIS server. It sounds just like there was an authentication filter and haven't been isolated by system session.  You might need to capture the request with fiddler and check failed request tracing log. Besides, send username/password to server is pure client-side behavior. Please ensure your browser is considering your site as local intranet.

Comment: @JokiesDing Hello, thank you for your comment. I did try to turn on/off the impersonate feature under CGI settings in IIS with no success. Both Remote and Logon user in phpinfo are the same as seen on the above screenshot (the logon user is changed, but it shows the incorrect, admin user in PHPinfo as well). When I try to get into the app, it requests me to log in with the popup window, after that, it connects me properly. But that's not a solution for me as I want it to have automatic connection (so-to-say SSO with NTLM/WindowsAuth). Browser is considering the site as local intranet as well.